# uWSGI log format to capture request number and count

Tags: python, uwsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi, uwsgi-stats-server

The default log format includes the request number and number of requests.  However I don't see a way to reference those variables in a custom log format.

Any idea how I can sprinkle them in?

*(see the ??? here)*

```
log-format = [pid: %(pid)|app: ???|req: ???/???] %(addr) (%(user)) {%(vars) vars in %(pktsize) bytes} [%(ctime)] %(method) %(uri) => generated %(rsize) bytes in %(msecs) msecs (%(proto) %(status)) %(headers) headers in %(hsize) bytes (%(switches) switches on core %(core)) %(var.HTTP_STARTTIMESTAMP) %(var.HTTP_REFERER)
```

Comment: Try `app: -|req: -/-`?

Comment: I think the OP asks how to replicate the actual default uWSGI log format with an overridden `logformat` pattern (in order to tweak it later, but first get what's in the default one). The [official docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LogFormat.html#uwsgi-default-logging) omit the placeholders for `app` and `req` components and it is not clear how to get those in a custom log format.

Answer (score 1):

The [default log format](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LogFormat.html#uwsgi-default-logging) for uWSGI is as follows:

```
log-format = [pid: %(pid)|app: -|req: -/-] %(addr) (%(user)) {%(vars) vars in %(pktsize) bytes} [%(ctime)] %(method) %(uri) => generated %(rsize) bytes in %(msecs) msecs (%(proto) %(status)) %(headers) headers in %(hsize) bytes (%(switches) switches on core %(core))
```

`app: -|req: -/-` appear to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Not what I am asking. In the standard logging I am seeing the worker and requests as a count. My custom logging I have no way to reference those variables. -/- is worthless and what its showing now.

Comment: @LiteWait not sure what you mean. You said you want those values (as they show in the default format) -- why can't you use that portion of the default format?